# Random exhaustive (non-repeating) selection from a large pool of entries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, random, indexing

Suppose I have a large (300-500k) collection of text documents stored in the relational database. Each document can belong to one or more (up to six) categories. I need users to be able to randomly select documents in a specific category so that a single entity is never repeated, much like how StumbleUpon works.

I don't really see a way I could implement this using slow NOT IN queries with large amount of users and documents, so I figured I might need to implement some custom data structure for this purpose. Perhaps there is already a paper describing some algorithm that might be adapted to my needs?

Currently I'm considering the following approach:

- Read all the entries from the database
- Create a linked list based index for each category from the IDs of documents belonging to the this category. Shuffle it
- Create a Bloom Filter containing all of the entries viewed by a particular user
- Traverse the index using the iterator, randomly select items using Bloom Filter to pick not viewed items.

Comment: Does the collection grow over time, or is it fixed? Also, do you want different randomizations of the documents in category for any given user, or is it OK for different users to see the same random ordering? (I would assume it's not OK, but the approach you're considering seems to involve a fixed randomization per category...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you track via a table what entries that the user has seen... try this. And I'm going to use mysql because that's the quickest example I can think of but the gist should be clear.

On a link being 'used'...

```
insert into viewed (userid, url_id) values ("jj", 123)
```

On looking for a link...

```
select p.url_id
from pages p left join viewed v on v.url_id = p.url_id
where v.url_id is null
order by rand()
limit 1
```

This causes the database to go ahead and do a 1 for 1 join, and your limiting your query to return only one entry that the user has not seen yet.

Just a suggestion.

Edit: It is possible to make this one operation but there's no guarantee that the url will be passed successfully to the user.

Comment: Contrary to what I initally thought anti-join solution worked OK. Coupled with preemptive fetching and caching this should do the trick. BTW, what did you mean by "there's no guarantee that the url will be passed successfully to the user."

Comment: If you make it one operation, a call to the database that returns the url and also marks it as 'used', then the database's work is done and it's up to other components to ensure that the information gets used. For example: If your program calls it and then crashes, 500 error or what nots... the database still considered that a good call and the url will not show up even if you fix the 500 later on.

Answer (score 2):

It depend on how users get it's random entries.

**Option 1:**

A user is paging some entities and stop after couple of them. for example the user see the current random entity and then moving to the next one, read it and continue it couple of times and that's it.
in the next time this user (or another) get an entity from this category the entities that already viewed is clear and you can return an already viewed entity.

in that option I would recommend save a (hash) set of already viewed entities id and every time user ask for a random entity- randomally choose it from the DB and check if not already in the set.

because the set is so small and your data is so big, the chance that you get an already viewed id is so small, that it will take O(1) most of the time.

**Option 2:**

A user is paging in the entities and the viewed entities are saving between all users and every time user visit your page.
in that case you probably use all the entities in each category and saving all the viewed entites + check whether a entity is viewed will take some time.

In that option I would get all the ids for this topic- shuffle them and store it in a linked list. when you want to get a random not viewed entity- just get the head of the list and delete it (O(1)).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for any given <user, category> pair, the number of documents viewed is pretty small relative to the total number of documents available in that category.

So can you just store indexed triples <user, category, document> indicating which documents have been viewed, and then just take an optimistic approach with respect to randomly selected documents? In the vast majority of cases, the randomly selected document will be unread by the user. And you can check quickly because the triples are indexed.

Comment: Like I said, a single document can belong to multiple categories, just like SO question can have many tags. And I believe that performance will quickly degrade once the user has viewed many items. I might as well just use NOT IN queries.

Comment: Algorithms like this are strongly dependent on the assumptions you make. You are right that performance will degrade as the user reads more and more documents. But again I'm assuming that the categories have tens of thousands of documents each, and that most users will have read far fewer than the 50K+ documents available in any given category. Are those wrong assumptions?

Comment: This might work, but I believe there might be a more efficient solution

Comment: I don't have any serious doubts about that, but keep in mind the space/time tradeoff. Under reasonable assumptions, the solution I'm describing will almost always involve a single pick and a single indexed check (good time performance), and I believe spacewise it involves storing the minimal amount of information required. The problem is that it starts breaking down if many users violate the assumptions. (If a handful do, no biggie.) Storing randomized lists per user category buys you better time scalability, but at what space cost?

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a pseudorandom approach:

1.) Determine number of elements in category to be viewed (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ...)
2.) Pick a random number in range 1 ... count.
3.) Select a single document (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE [same as when counting] ORDER BY [generate stable order]. Depending on the SQL dialect in use, there are different clauses that can be used to retrieve only the part of the result set you want (MySQL LIMIT clause, SQLServer TOP clause etc.)

If the number of documents is large the chance serving the same user the same document twice is neglibly small. Using the scheme described above you don't have to store *any* state information at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a nosql solution like Apache Cassandra.  These seem to be ideally suited to your needs.  There are many ways to design the algorithm you need in an environment where you can easily add new columns to a table (column family) on the fly, with excellent support for a very sparsely populated table.

edit: **one of many possible solutions below:**

1. create a CF(column family ie table) for each category (creating these on-the-fly is quite easy).
2. Add a row to each category CF for each document belonging to the category.
3. Whenever a user hits a document, you add a column with named  and set it to true to the row.  Obviously this table will be huge with millions of columns and probably quite sparsely populated, but no problem, reading this is still constant time.
4. Now finding a new document for a user in a category is simply a matter of selecting any result from select * where  == null.

You should get constant time writes and reads, amazing scalability, etc if you can accept Cassandra's "eventually consistent" model (ie, it is not mission critical that a user never get a duplicate document)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved similar in the past by indexing the relational database into a document oriented form using [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). This was before the recent rise of NoSQL servers and is basically the same thing, but it's still a valid alternative approach.

You would create a Lucene [Document](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/index.html) for each of your texts with a textId (relational database id) field and multi valued categoryId and userId fields. Populate the categoryId field appropriately. When a user reads a text, add their id to the userId field. A simple query will return the set of documents with a given categoryId and without a given userId - pick one randomly and display it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store a users past X selections in a cookie or something.
2. Return the last selections to the server with the users new criteria
3. Randomly choose one of the texts satisfying the criteria until it is not a member of the last X selections of the user.
4. Return this choice of text and update the list of last X selections.

I would experiment to find the best value of X but I have in mind something like an X of say 16?